# Meteor collection2 is allowing numbers as strings

Tags: meteor-collection2

I am starting a new Meteor project and am using Collection2 for validation. I have the below schema defined. When I insert a document with title: 4, I expect it to fail since I have specified it as a String. It is not failing. I suspect there is some fundamental aspect of Meteor I'm not getting. FYI, if I leave out the title, I get the expected errors.

My schema:

```
Timestamps = new Mongo.Collection('timestamps');

var Schemas = {};

Schemas.Timestamp = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    max: 500,
    optional: false
  },
  notes: {
    type: String,
    label: "Notes",
    max: 1000,
    optional: true
  }
});

Timestamps.attachSchema(Schemas.Timestamp);
```

The following code should fail with an error saying title needs to be a String. However, it is not failing, and the value is being stored as a string "4".

Creating a timestamp:

```
Timestamps.insert({title: 4, comments: "a comment"});
```

This is how I am publishing and allowing timestamp inserts.

```
Meteor.publish("timestamps", function() {
    return Timestamps.find();
});

Timestamps.allow({
    insert: function(timestamp) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation:

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#skip-conversion-of-values-to-match-what-schema-expects

Collection2 has an option (default true) to try to match data types